# android: getSystemService calling from a non extended activity class not working

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to test the internet connection of my app, and I'm testing it with "ConnectivityManager".

I'would like to call the ConnectivityManager class not from the main class, but from a class a made just to handel the connectivity test.

the method "getSystemService" in the second class gives me an error, how come???

This is the main class calling the connectivitymanager class:

```
   public void onClick(View v){
        Log.d("mytag", "in onclick");
   CheckInternetpermission obCheckInternetPermission= new CheckInternetpermission();
        Log.d("mytag", "starting permission");
        obCheckInternetPermission.check();
    }
```

This is the connectivitymanager, "getSystemService" gives me this error: Cannot resolve method 'getSystemService(java.lang.String)

```
package com.example.network;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;


public class CheckInternetpermission{
    public void check(){
        Log.d("mytag", "In check");
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)


getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); //<---getSystemService give me error??????
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                Log.d("mytag", "Internet connection TRUE");
            } else {
                Log.d("mytag","Internet connection FALSE");    // display error
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getSystemService()` is a method on `Context`. You need to have a `Context` to obtain a system service. Your `Activity`, for example, is a `Context`, as the `Activity` class inherits from `Context`.

Comment: should the check() method be defined as check(Context context)?? how can I solve it? Or better how can I pass a context to the getSystemService() method?